# Do LINQ statements have inferior performace compared to their SQL equivalents?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In a few scenarios I have observed that, the LINQ statement's performance, as measured through SQL Server Profiler, is less than half of that of the SQL statement for the same query.  Is this the case always or could be due to poor construction of LINQ statements?

Following is an example of SQL query and its LINQ version where there is a major performance difference:-

```
SQL: 
SELECT * FROM persDetails p
INNER JOIN level q
ON p.levelId = q.id AND q.level = 1
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from persDetails)

LINQ:
var result = from p in persDetails
             join  q in level on p.levelId equals q.level
             where q.level = 1
             join r in (from n in persDetails group n by n.departmentId into g select new { maxDate = g.Max(t => t.date)})
             on p.date equals r.maxDate
             select p;
```

Table: *persDetails*

```
|id | persID | name | salary |    date   | LevelId |departmentID |
|---|--------|------|--------|-----------|---------|-------------|   
| 1 | 1      | John | $500   |2017/03/01 |  1      |   1         |
| 2 | 2      | Mary | $300   |2017/03/01 |  2      |   1         |
| 3 | 3      | Alice| $550   |2017/03/01 |  1      |   1         |
| 4 | 2      | Mary | $300   |2017/02/01 |  2      |   1         |
| 5 | 1      | John | $450   |2017/02/01 |  1      |   1         |
| 6 | 3      | Alice| $500   |2017/02/01 |  1      |   1         |
```

Table: *level*

```
|id | LevelName | level |
|---|-----------|-------|
| 1 |   CEO     |  1    |
| 2 |   CTO     |  1    |
| 3 |General Mgr|  2    |
```

*Expected result*

```
|id | persID | name | salary |    date   | LevelId |
|---|--------|------|--------|-----------|---------| 
| 1 |  1     | John | $500   |2017/03/01 | 1       |
| 2 |  3     | Alice| $550   |2017/03/01 | 1       |
```

Comment: LINQ statements are then converted into plain SQL queries. You could just use SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are generated by LINQ and compare it to hand-written. Usually, LINQ queries are as performant as hand-written, but sometimes not. It is autogenerated and cannot perfectly fit any requirements.

Comment: Btw, you LINQ query is much more complex, has more selects and joins, than your SQL query. It MUST be less performant. Your SQL-query also just uses `max(date)`, without grouping, these two queries, probably, lead to different results.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I've seen the converted SQL query in the profiler and it is not similar to the one written by me. I can't think of converting the above sql into a better LINQ code. It is converting to SQL with two joins !

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Can you please suggest the simplified LINQ version of the SQL above. Thanks

Comment: You can get good or poor performance with both LINQ and handwritten SQL. It depends on how you write each query. Either way you should be analysing the performance, including the generated SQL, for both implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ statements are then converted into plain SQL queries. You could just use SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are generated by LINQ and compare it to hand-written. Usually, LINQ queries are as performant as hand-written, but not always - it is an autogenerated query and cannot always perfectly fit any requirements.

Talking about your queries, they are just different and, probably, lead to different results. Your LINQ query is much more complex than your SQL query - it has more selects and joins and uses join to find max date. It MUST be less performant.

The following LINQ query would be a full analogue of your SQL query:

```
var result = from p in persDetails
             join q in level on p.levelId equals q.level
             where q.level == 1 and p.date == persDetails.Max(x => x.date)
             select p;
```

It will result into the similar query and should take the same amount of time to execute.

Comment: Would simply having `and p.date = persDetails.Max(x => x.date)` not work? Rather than having two return trips to the database

Comment: @Rob I wasn't sure about that, but I've tested it and it should work. Sometimes, I wonder how smart these LINQ providers are :) Thank you for correction.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, @Rob Thanks a lot to both of you. The proposed LINQ query has definitely resulted in performance improvement. However the original SQL runs with `CPU time=0ms, elapsed time=8ms` but the SQL statement generated by LINQ query runs with `CPU time=16ms, elapsed time=8ms`.  Both have been run in the SQL Management Studio.